# Symbols distorting in Sketch3

Tags: sketch-app

I'm having an issue with one particular symbol that "distorts" itself whenever I place it on an artboard (or into another symbol). 
So the symbol in question is called "Arrow Froward" looks like this. [image: arrow symbol]

However, when placed the rectangle at the bottom becomes distorted.

[image: broken arrow]

I've tried quitting Sketch, I've messed around with that rectangle at the bottom, and I can change how it looks on the artboard by making it larger or smaller but I haven't been able to get it to line up and look exactly as it does in the symbol.  All other symbols are working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out: turns out my symbol instance was distorted.  The symbol itself is 33x33 but the instance was like 35x47.  I brought it to the correct ratio and it looks fine.